# Set program as default .exe opener

Tags: c#, .net, exe, antivirus

I was trying to make a simple **antivirus program** that checks exes as they are launched.

My idea was to **make my application the default exe opener**, then scan the file before launching it.

However I can't seem to find a way to set my program to open exe files, **I've done it for other file types**, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I'm genuinely interested if this **is possible, or do I have to find a workaround?**

Thnx to anyone who can help!

Comment: You really don't want to set anything as the default application to open a file of type `.exe` with.

Comment: does that cause issues?

Comment: There is no such thing as "a **simple** antivirus program". (emphasis by me)

Comment: The way virus scanners work, is by using a kernal mode filter driver, and monitors CreateProcess ect. I think your idea is majorly flawed and bound to cause issues, and could potentially kill your system if you manage to do it

Comment: I like the idea, even though you obviously need to prevent infinite recursion. I suppose though that the usual way AntiVirus programs work is to indirect or "hijack" the system `open`  call (on modern Windowses probably through an official operating system mechanism). That makes sense because viruses also infect non-exe files like office documents.

Comment: so from a practical standpoint, I probably shouldn't try to make an Antivirus?

Comment: Who are we to judge, however i think there are easier fish to catch than writing a virus scanner

Comment: Practically speaking, you shouldn't. As an exercise it is great though, perhaps you have some new ideas, and if you are good enough you'll be rich. So give it a go ;-).

Comment: I'll look further into the topic and see if i can figure it out.

Comment: Thnx everyone for the help :)
Probably should remove the question then, it's kinda irrelevant to anyone else.

Comment: you can (for practice purpose) listen for file opening [events using the WMI](https://www.varonis.com/blog/practical-powershell-for-it-security-part-i-file-event-monitoring/) and check files are being opened in parallel. This is not true antivirus (you can't prevent file from being opened) but you can get some info about the file and check it for viruses. There is .Net [ManagementEventWatcher](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementeventwatcher?view=netframework-4.8) available to do it. However antivirus is much more about virus signature database collection.